# Update service log at each print

Tags: systemd, python, logs, rsyslog

I have a couple of Python scripts running as services, which periodically (for instance, every minute) print something.

By checking the system logs, I noticed that these periodic prints are someway grouped and printed into the log less frequently (for example, I see about 50 lines with the same timestamp).

Is it possible to tell the service to separately save each print into the log file, instead of grouping them? If yes, how? Should I someway edit the `rsyslog.conf` file?

Comment: chances are your python print statements are being *buffered*, and really reach the log en block (but at these frequencies, I'd be slightly surprised!). Can you try disabling buffering for the python process? Or even better, use Python's `logging` module instead of `print()` for logging?

Comment: We need many more details. My **total guess** is that your scripts are "logging" by printing to stdout. By default this is buffered if the output is not going to a terminal. Adding the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` or using `python -u scriptname args` my fix things. Editing rsyslog.conf will not help. There is also the command `stdbuf -oL` which can help.

Comment: Which version of python?  Newer versions (3.7? Or 3.9? Not sure) default to unbuffered or line buffered; older versions you can turn it off with the `-u` flag.  https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u